# not showing bengali equation as output in latex

Tags: equations, babel

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[inner=1.5cm, outer=1.5cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage[bidi=basic,layout=sectioning]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\babelprovide[onchar=fonts ids]{bengali}
\babelprovide[import,main]{english}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase, Ligatures=TeX, Renderer=HarfBuzz}

%% These fonts are abailable at: https://www.google.com/get/noto/
\babelfont{rm}
[Ligatures=Common,Scale=1.0,Language=Default]{Times New Roman}
\babelfont{sf}
[Language=Default]{Times New Roman}
\babelfont{tt}
[Language=Default]{Times New Roman}
\babelfont[bengali]{rm}
[Language=Default]{Noto Serif Bengali}
\babelfont[bengali]{sf}
[Language=Default]{Noto Sans Bengali}
\babelfont[bengali]{tt}
[Language=Default]{Noto Sans Bengali UI}

\babeltags{english=english}
\babeltags{bengali=bengali}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
%\usepackage{unicode-math}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%for image
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

%%for drawining
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,shapes.arrows,calc}

%%%for table 
\usepackage{tabularray}







\begin{document}    
        $e=\frac{ সংঘাতের পর বস্তুদ্বয়ের অপসারণ বেগ }{সংঘাতের পূর্বে বস্তুদ্বয়ের আগমন বেগ}$     
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome. I don't know why others have down voted and voted to close. The question would be better if you describe the problem and your expectations in a few sentences.

Comment: Welcome. // Please remove the lines of codes, e.g. packages or settings, which are not relevant here to show your problem.

Comment: I would suggest to switch to text mode `$e=\frac{\textrm{সংঘাতের পর বস্তুদ্বয়ের অপসারণ বেগ }}{\textrm{সংঘাতের পূর্বে বস্তুদ্বয়ের আগমন বেগ}}$`

Comment: @Ingmar it is a 1-line document which shows a good attempt at being a MWE, I voted to re-open

Comment: @UlrikeFischer post as answer?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle done

Comment: It's still far from a *minimal* example, and a few words (or perhaps an image) explaining the discrepancy between expected and obtained result wouldn't have hurt, but it's all sorted now, so that's a moot point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The math fonts don't know how to handle bengali. I would suggest to switch temporarly to text mode:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[inner=1.5cm, outer=1.5cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage[bidi=basic,layout=sectioning]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\babelprovide[onchar=fonts ids]{bengali}
\babelprovide[import,main]{english}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase, Ligatures=TeX, Renderer=HarfBuzz}

%% These fonts are abailable at: https://www.google.com/get/noto/
\babelfont{rm}
[Ligatures=Common,Scale=1.0,Language=Default]{Times New Roman}
\babelfont{sf}
[Language=Default]{Times New Roman}
\babelfont{tt}
[Language=Default]{Times New Roman}
\babelfont[bengali]{rm}
[Language=Default]{Noto Serif Bengali}
\babelfont[bengali]{sf}
[Language=Default]{Noto Sans Bengali}

\babeltags{english=english}
\babeltags{bengali=bengali}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}

\begin{document}
        
 $e=\frac{\textrm{সংঘাতের পর বস্তুদ্বয়ের অপসারণ বেগ }}{\textrm{সংঘাতের পূর্বে বস্তুদ্বয়ের আগমন বেগ}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you boss..